# perl poe tcp server handle multiple clients

Tags: perl, tcp

Hi i have a POE TCP SERVER, it needs to be HANDLE MULTIPLE CLIENTS. New client connects and it  requests server to 'start send data' and server will starts sending data, when client requests server to 'stop send data' and server will stop sending data. This should happen to multiple clients. I tried it but it handles only one client. Below is the code for it please help me how to solve this issue?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use POE;
use POE::Component::Server::TCP;
use Data::Dumper;

POE::Component::Server::TCP->new(
    Alias              => "server",
    Port               => 2000,
    ClientFilter => 'POE::Filter::Stream',
    ClientArgs => [
        $ARGV[0]
    ],
    Started => sub {
        my ($session, $heap) = @_[SESSION, HEAP];
        print STDERR "Server started\n";
    },
    ClientConnected    => sub {
        my($session, $kernel, $heap) = @_[SESSION, KERNEL, HEAP];
        $kernel->alias_set('Downloader');
        $heap->{current_state} = "waiting for command";
        $heap->{START} = 0;
        $heap->{STOP} = 0;
        $heap->{isStopPending} = 0;
        $heap->{sessionID} = $_[SESSION]->ID;
    },
    ClientInput        => sub {
        my ($heap, $kernel, $session, $input) = @_[HEAP, KERNEL, SESSION, ARG0];
        $heap->{input} .= $input;
        process_data ($heap,$session,$kernel);
    },

    InlineStates       => {
        StartSending => sub {
            my ($heap, $kernel, $session) = @_[HEAP, KERNEL, SESSION];
            $kernel->post('Downloader', 'OnSending');
        },
        OnSending => sub {
            my ($heap, $kernel, $session) = @_[HEAP, KERNEL, SESSION];
            if ($heap->{isStopPending} != 0 ) {
                  $heap->{isStopPending} = 0;
                  print STDERR "Stopped to session $heap->{sessionID}...\n";
                  return;
            }else {
                  print STDERR "Sending to SessionID: $heap->{sessionID}\n";
                  read_file ($heap);
                  $heap->{client}->put($heap->{data});
                  $heap->{data} = '';
                  $kernel->alarm(OnSending=> time() + 1, 0);
            }
         },
        StopWasRequested => sub {
             my ($heap, $kernel, $session) = @_[HEAP, KERNEL, SESSION];
             $heap->{isStopPending} = 1;
             print STDERR "Stop was requested\n";
        },
    },
);

sub process_data {
    my ($heap, $session, $kernel) = @_;
    if ($heap->{current_state} eq "waiting for command") {
        process_Command ($heap);
        if ($heap->{command} eq "START") {
            $heap->{current_state} = "waiting for command";
            Start ($heap, $kernel, $session);
        } elsif ($heap->{command} eq "STOP") {
            $heap->{current_state} = "waiting for command";
            Stop ($heap, $kernel, $session);
        }
    }
    return;
}
sub process_Command {
    my ($heap) = @_;
    my $input = $heap->{input};
    my $length = length($input);
    $input =~ s/^(.{$length})//;
    $heap->{input} = $input;
    $heap->{command} = $1;
    return;
}
sub Start {
    my ($heap, $kernel, $session) = @_;
    return if ($heap->{START} == 1);
    $heap->{START} = 1;
    $heap->{STOP} = 0;
    $kernel->yield('StartSending');
}

sub Stop {
    my ($heap, $kernel, $session) = @_;
    $heap->{STOP} = 1;
    $heap->{START} = 0;
    print STDERR "Stop...\n";
    $kernel->post($heap->{sessionID}=>'StopWasRequested');
}

sub read_file {
    my ($heap) = @_;
    my $filesize = -s "0001.out";
    open (RF, "<0001.out") or die "could not open file";
    binmode (RF);
    read (RF, my $data, $filesize);
    close (RF);
    $heap->{data} = $data;
    return;
}

$poe_kernel->run();
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ClientConnected callback, `$kernel->alias_set('Downloader');` statement applies to very first connecting client(session), subsequent clients(sessions) should not set with same alias 'Downloader'. In 'StartSending' callback of InsliStates, post destination is 'Downloader' so that server sends data to very first connecting client. To send data to multiple clients use SESSION_ID as destination instead-of ALIAS in this case 'Downloader'. So replace:

```
$kernel->post('Downloader', 'OnSending');
```

by

```
$kernel->post($_[SESSION]->ID=>'OnSending');
```

in "StartSending" callback of Inlinestates. So it works fine now.